# Half volley shot of cricket

Tags: cricket, terminology

The half volley is a tennis shot but why this word entered in cricket and what is half volley shot of cricket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the Half-volley is not a shot type but a delivery type (in terms of pitching). This type of delivery pitches ahead of a good length but not too fuller(which ends up in full-toss). I.e. it pitches between good length and full toss. Batsmen can easily drive such delivery.

May be the reason behind it's name is: The ball pitches near foot same as in tennis.

See the terms in [a glossary of cricket terms by ESPNCricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/239756.html).